# Symfony cannot get twig table in jquery table

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

In twig i have this :

```
{% for item in apps%}
<li id="appli" >{{ item.appliname }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

That give me this:

sandale
t-shirt
pull
yield

Now i wanna pass the twig table "apps" in my jquery script, so i tried this :

```
var v = new Array();
v = JSON.parse('{{ apps | json_encode | raw }}');            
console.log(v);
```

ouput :
[Object {}, Object {}, Object {}, Object {}]

So how can i get the result in a table like: [sandale, t-shirt, pull, yield] ?

PLZ Help

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `json_encode` cannot traverse `private` class members.

You will need to use some serializer, for example, [**Serializer**](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) (bundle:  [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)) in order to do that

Hope this helps...

Comment: when i put this in jquery it give me only the first item: var v = $("#appli").html();            
            console.log(v);

Answer (score 0):

I found it by using this :

```
var all = $("#appli").map(function() {
return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
```